# How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload

There's a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) object in JavaScript.  I want to instantiate one for testing purposes.

I have tried `new File()`, but I get an "Illegal constructor" error.

Is it possible to create a `File` object ?

---

*File Object reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File*

Comment: MDN link has changed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Answer (score 270, accepted):

According to the W3C File API specification, the File constructor requires 2 (or 3) parameters.

So to create a empty file do:

```
var f = new File([""], "filename");
```

- The first argument is the data provided as an array of lines of text;
- The second argument is the filename ;
- The third argument looks like:

  ```
  var f = new File([""], "filename.txt", {type: "text/plain", lastModified: date})
  ```

It works in FireFox, Chrome and Opera, but not in Safari or IE/Edge.

Comment: Produces `Illegal constructor` on Chrome 37 / Ubuntu so no it does not work

Comment: This does work in Firefox 28+, Chrome 38+ and Opera 25+.However, Safari and IE still do not implement this constructor today (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi). I'm currently looking for a polyfill or a way to emulate this, but did'nt find any suitable solution so far.

Comment: @PA.Buisson I'm not sure if this holds for all cases(it was sufficient for me), but you can use the Blob() constructor instead, as suggested [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/html5/file-api/)

Comment: What is alternative of this for windows edge?

Comment: Works in Safari as of Jun 19, 2018. version: Safari 11.1.1.

Comment: How do you do this in nodeJS?

Comment: For IE11, you can use the Blob class to construct a File object. This seems to be the most portable solution to me.

`file = new Blob([blobdata], {type: filetype, lastModified: filelastModified}); file.name = filename`

Comment: Does anyone know, how to get the path of the file?.

Comment: I had to do something similar as Jesse Hogan suggested because TypeScript overrides the File class and changes its constructor to one that does not accept a blob.

Answer (score 38):

Now you can!

```js
var parts = [
  new Blob(['you construct a file...'], {type: 'text/plain'}),
  ' Same way as you do with blob',
  new Uint16Array([33])
];

// Construct a file
var file = new File(parts, 'sample.txt', {
    lastModified: new Date(0), // optional - default = now
    type: "overide/mimetype" // optional - default = ''
});

var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function(evt){
   document.body.innerHTML = evt.target.result + "<br><a href="+URL.createObjectURL(file)+" download=" + file.name + ">Download " + file.name + "</a><br>type: "+file.type+"<br>last modified: "+ file.lastModifiedDate
}

fr.readAsText(file);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work in Chrome.  See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164933.  Verified that it doesn't work in Chrome 36 OSX.

Comment: then i will Verify that it DOSE work in Chrome 35 OSX when you run `new File([], '')`

Comment: Just tested, it doesn't work in 35 either.  Please adjust your answer to reflect the fact that this only works in Firefox.

Comment: hmm, you are right. it did only work for me since i had activated a experimental chrome flag... https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3464804/jCmQr8vrGk.gif

Comment: Produces `Illegal constructor` on Chrome 37 / Ubuntu

Comment: Working in Chrome 45 for me

Answer (score 19):

> **Update**
>
> BlobBuilder has been [obsoleted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder) see how you go using it, if you're using it for testing purposes.
>
> Otherwise apply the below with migration strategies of going to *Blob*, such as the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030906/how-to-replace-the-deprecated-blobbuilder-with-the-new-blob-constructor).

#### Use a Blob instead

As an alternative there is a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob) that you can use in place of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) as it is what File interface derives from as per [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file):

```
interface File : Blob {
    readonly attribute DOMString name;
    readonly attribute Date lastModifiedDate;
};
```

> The File interface is based on Blob, inheriting blob functionality and expanding it to support files on the user's system.

#### Create the Blob

Using the [BlobBuilder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/BlobBuilder) like this on an existing JavaScript method that takes a File to upload via `XMLHttpRequest` and supplying a Blob to it works fine like this:

```
var BlobBuilder = window.MozBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder;
var bb = new BlobBuilder();

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png', true);

xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

bb.append(this.response); // Note: not xhr.responseText

//at this point you have the equivalent of: new File()
var blob = bb.getBlob('image/png');

/* more setup code */
xhr.send(blob);
```

#### Extended example

The rest of the sample is up on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NickJosevski/VTSUs/) in a more complete fashion but will not successfully upload as I can't expose the upload logic in a long term fashion.

Comment: This comment is out of date. Do not use BlobBuilder, use Blob constructor. Blob(['mythingy'], { type: "thingy" })

Comment: This code does not run. TypeError: BlobBuilder is not a constructor

Comment: Unfortunately, BlobBuilder is obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BlobBuilder

Comment: `DataTransferItemList.add` requires `File` not `Blob`. So to the original question: How to instantiate **File**?

Answer (score 5):

Now it's possible and supported by all major browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File

```
var file = new File(["foo"], "foo.txt", {
  type: "text/plain",
});
```

Comment: As much as it pains me to say this, edge is a major browser.

Comment: I didn't see much people using it actually. https://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi - IE 2.6%, Edge - 1.4%, Opera Mini - 2.7%. On https://netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx is 4.3%. If you care about Edge then need to find some workaround https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/9551546/

Comment: Evestigneev you've misinterpreted the results as the supported browsers have a global use of around 0.2%. This figure is how many browsers are using the api while edge / IE itself make up around 15% of browsers still in use.

Answer (score 2):

The idea ...To create a File object (api) in javaScript for images already present in the DOM :

```
<img src="../img/Products/fijRKjhudDjiokDhg1524164151.jpg">

var file = new File(['fijRKjhudDjiokDhg1524164151'],
                     '../img/Products/fijRKjhudDjiokDhg1524164151.jpg', 
                     {type:'image/jpg'});

// created object file
console.log(file);
```

Don't do that ! ... (but I did it anyway)

-> the console give a result similar as an Object File :

```
File(0) {name: "fijRKjokDhgfsKtG1527053050.jpg", lastModified: 1527053530715, lastModifiedDate: Wed May 23 2018 07:32:10 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 0, …}
lastModified:1527053530715
lastModifiedDate:Wed May 23 2018 07:32:10 GMT+0200 (Paris, Madrid (heure d’été)) {}
name:"fijRKjokDhgfsKtG1527053050.jpg"
size:0
type:"image/jpg"
webkitRelativePath:""__proto__:File
```

But the size of the object is wrong ...

Why i need to do that ?

For example to retransmit
 an image form already uploaded, during a product update, along with additional images added during the update

Answer (score -4):

Because this is javascript and dynamic you could define your own class that matches the File interface and use that instead.

I had to do just that with dropzone.js because I wanted to simulate a file upload and it works on File objects.