# Create a file object from an img tag

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say that I have an img tag with a base64 src like :

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS..." id="id">
```

How can I create a File object (containing the data of the img tag) alike an object I would get after an user chose a file from a file input ? In order to upload it to a server later.

Like that one :

```
File { name: "a22919a70cf8458d654642e0bc2cd881.jpg", lastModified: 1521393615000, lastModifiedDate: Date 2018-03-18T17:20:15.000Z, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 40635, type: "image/jpeg" }
```

I'm not looking for getting a BLOB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a File object from binary data in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18283772/how-to-create-a-file-object-from-binary-data-in-javascript)

Comment: @SunnyPatel No, at the end the user create a BLOB and not a File object like you would get with a file input.

Answer (score 26):

You could always create a blob first and then convert that to a file.

But you hardly ever need a File instance. It will give you more headache trying to construct them then just using the blob. If you need to upload them to a server you need to use `FormData`. And when you do you can append a blob and set the filename as a 3th argument
 `fd.append(field, blob, filename)` instead of appending a file

The file constructor arguments are the same as blob except between the `parts` and the `options` you pass in the filename.

File Object inherits the Blob object so you use them the same way in other apis as well

```
new File([parts], filename, options)
new Blob([parts], options)
```

Other thing is that different is file supports 1 more option... lastModified
IE/Edge can have Files but the constructor don't work. that's why you should use blobs...

```js
const img = document.getElementById('id')

fetch(img.src)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', blob)
  console.log(file)
})
```

```html
<img id="id" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==">
```

Answer (score 3):

The File Object inherits the Blob object, so it is very close to being the same.

The code below shows a successfully generated File "Blob" object can be used to generate a object url which downloads the image.

( Note: on stack overflow the blob url has a null host which causes it to not to automatically download as a file, but you can still use right click save as. See [URL.createObjectURL returns a blob with null prepended. Eg : Blob:null/12415-63](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377733/url-createobjecturl-returns-a-blob-with-null-prepended-eg-blobnull-12415-63) )

```js
// https://bl.ocks.org/nolanlawson/0eac306e4dac2114c752 
let dataUrl = document.getElementById("img1").src.split(',')
let base64 = dataUrl[1];
let mime = dataUrl[0].match(/:(.*?);/)[1];
let bin = atob(base64);
let length = bin.length;
// From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967647/ (continues on next line)
// encode-decode-image-with-base64-breaks-image (2013-04-21)
let buf = new ArrayBuffer(length);
let arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
bin
  .split('')
  .forEach((e,i)=>arr[i]=e.charCodeAt(0));
  
let f = new File([buf],'filename',{type:mime}); // note: [buf]
let blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(f);
let link = document.createElement("a"); 
link.href = blobUrl;
link.download = "filename";
link.innerHTML = "Download file.";
document.getElementById("url1").appendChild(link);
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="data:image/png;base64, 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">
<div id="url1"></div>
```