# using fetch and returning file object

Tags: javascript

I came across following piece of code

```
const img = document.getElementById('id')
fetch(img.src)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
  const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', blob)
  console.log(file)
})
```

at the following url

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49925039/create-a-file-object-from-an-img-tag
```

What I am trying to do is declare a variable

```
var file = fetch(img.src)
           .then(res => res.blob())
           .then(blob => {
            const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', blob)
            return file;
           });
 //then I want to use this file object here
```

However problem is my lack of understanding of fetch api, it seems main javascript would not wait for fetch to return the result into my file variable. Can some one please help me so that above piece of code will return a file object in my main javascript process so that I can use it elsewhere?
Thanks
**Update:**
After seeing the responses, I did the following

```
async function CallAsyncFunction(img){
    var file = await fetch(img.src)
       .then(res => res.blob())
       .then(blob => {
        const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', blob)
        return file;
       });
    return file;
 }
let file;
CallAsyncFunction(imgrc).then(resp=>{
  file=resp;
  //file here is correct object
});
console.log(file.name);//still no data in the main js code..what am I doing    wrong..:-(
```

Comment: Your last code block is equal to: `async function CallAsyncFunction(img){ return fetch(img.src).then(res => res.blob()).then(blob => {
        const file = new File([blob], 'dot.png', blob)
        return file;
       })`

Comment: The `console.log(file.name);` has the be where your `//file here is correct object` comment is. Currently `console.log(file.name);` is executed before the file is fetched. That's how asynchronous code works. Please read the linked duplicate carefully.

Comment: Thanks for point to the other thread where this has been explained.
AuxTaco, connexo