# Passing values in to google maps api from text file on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to pass in the initial start values from a text file on the localhost.

Can someone please explain how to do this properly?

I've been trying to follow tutorials but they all assume the file is read in from a reader.

I don't know javascript very well.

This doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
</style>
<script>
    function initialize() {

        var lat = 0;
        var long = 0;

        var center = File("Center.txt");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var results = reader.result;
        }
        reader.readAsText(center);           
        var text = reader.result.toString();
        var stringAr = text.split(",");
        lat = stringAr[0];
        long = stringAr[1];


        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long)
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);


        map.data.loadGeoJson('test.json');
    }

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
            'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>   
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out all the file reader stuff it works, but I need to be able to pass in the lat long parameters without the user selecting anything.

Would I alternatively be able to read them from a json file and set it that way the same way I am with the data?

Comment: show us what the contents of your Center.txt file look like.  And what do you get if you output `console.log(text);` after you call `var text = reader.result.toString();`?

Comment: Ah I didn't know about the javascript console, there is no output but I get this error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I assume that line `var center = File("Center.txt");` is not correct. It seems that you cannot just use `File()` constructor. See some tutorials how to get `File` reference, for example [Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: See [How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the values you're reading from your text file are being saved as strings.  Google maps expects Number objects.  You can simply use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to fix this:

```
lat = parseFloat(stringAr[0]);
long = parseFloat(stringAr[1]);
```