# Set audio src using local file dynamically

Tags: javascript, file

In `Firefox`, I'm trying to load an audio file from the user's file system.
I've read that I can create a `File` object based on a path [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181292/595833)
The code will be run inside a firefox addon, so have access to privilaged code.

Any ideas why this is causing an error in console and for the `document.getElementById('player')` element to vanish?

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyrne01/sp5qr7hh/

^ fiddle is just for demonstration purposes, it will ultimately be run inside a firefox addon.

`html` ..

```
<audio id="player" preload="auto" controls></audio>
```

`js` ..

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(d) {
    console.log(d.target.result);
    document.getElementById('player').src = d.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(new File([""], "file:///home/rob/audio.mp3"));
```

console output ..

```
"data:application/octet-stream;base64," _display:24
HTTP "Content-Type" of "application/octet-stream" is not supported. Load of media resource data:application/octet-stream;base64, failed.
```

`filesystem` ..

```
rob@work:~$ pwd
/home/rob
rob@work:~$ ls audio.mp3 
audio.mp3
```

Comment: What's causing the spew -- the FileReader's attempt to load the file, or the <audio> tag not accepting the input?

Comment: Also, have you tried using the recommended HTML5 `<audio><source src="music.ogg" /></audio>` structure?

Comment: Add the correct `MIME Type` when creating the file stream.

Comment: @amphetamachine `document.getElementById('player').src = d.target.result;` was causing the error. @MelanciaUK do you mean `application/octet-stream`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you utilize the recommended HTML5 DOM structure for `<audio>` tags, it should work:

```
var sourceElem = document.createElement('source');
sourceElem.setAttribute('src', "file:///home/rob/audio.mp3");
document.getElementById('player').appendChild(sourceElem);
```

I got the jsfiddle to give me a security error saying it shouldn't load local resources.

Comment: I would really like to utilize `FileReader()` to load the audio file, since i'll then be using [JavaScript-ID3-Reader](https://github.com/aadsm/JavaScript-ID3-Reader#file-api) to read id3 data from the file

Answer (score 0):

Loading local files from via a remote website is a security issue. You'd also have to detect what system the user is using in order to get the proper file structure. Most browser prevent this sort of behavior, as you shouldn't be able to read any random file on a user's computer unless they put it in an upload form.

Your users would essentially have to run your site from a local copy (similar to a local webapp on iOS)

Comment: Your points are valid, I should have noted earlier in the question that the code is run inside a `Firefox addon`, so have access to privilaged code to determine platform etc.