# Javascript File variable declaration/creation Error: This Object does not support this action

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, authentication, registration

today i created a html doc. to code a login and registration website. My idea was the following: 
When you create an account, your data should be save in a text file (unsafe).
When you log in, the code should compare the input with the data in the file.
But when I want to initialize a variable for my File, Internet Explorer shows the following error: SCRIPT445: This object does not support this action.
The marked line I have here:

```html
//Here is the layout creation...
<script>
  function login() 
  {
    var username = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
    var kennwort = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
  }
  function register()
  {
    var rusername = document.getElementById("txtrusername").value;
    var remail = document.getElementById("txtremail").value;
    var rkennwort = document.getElementById("txtrpassword").value;
    var rconfirmpassword = document.getElementById("txtrconfirmpassword").value;
    if(rpassword!=rconfirmpassword)
    {
      alert(unescape("The passwords do not match!", "Error"));
      return;
    }

    //This line creates the error
    var file = new File("C:/Users/Konsicoder/Desktop/Data/data.txt");
    //This line creates the error

    alert("Success!", "Success");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `//` is not a comment in HTML.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of providing a local file system path and instantiating a File object, you'll likely need to use the browser file selector to be able to first get a handle of the local file.

[http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/][1]
[Reading files in JavaScript using the File APIs][1]

Here is a post on SO with details about how a File object can be instantiated:
[How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Comment: See? That's the problem when someone links the solution to something in an answer. It's gone. 404. Puff, There's no more solution for this question.