# Fetching images in React and converting it to File

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have some images in my react project's public folder. I can read them using fetch API, which gives me readablestream. I want to convert the output to type `File`. How can I do it? Example of the File type I'm looking for is given below.

```
const file = new File(['foo'], 'foo.jpg', {type: 'image/jpg'})
```

Purpose: An API I use only accept `File` type

Comment: What is the end goal?

Comment: I want to get a File variable type. I need File type to upload to an API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript creating a file from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35219960/javascript-creating-a-file-from-url)

Comment: what Content-type your api require? form data right?

Comment: I'm calling a library function, and it's using File type

Comment: @ChrisG it's about creating blob. It's a different type I guess

Comment: You mean that you want to convert the images which in your project's folder to the `File` then call the library function, right?

Comment: yes you're right

Comment: Yes, but all you need then is `const file = new File([blob], blob.type);`