# Initiate File type for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently just trying to read one file using FileReader(). Here is the code I have so far,

```
<script>
    var file = new File("file:///C:/path/to/file");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var block = document.getElementById("block");
      reader.onload = function(){
      block.innerText = reader.result;
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);
</script>
```

I get an error saying that I need **2 arguments** instead of **1 argument** when instantiating a new File.
What do I need for the first argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Comment: You can not achieve what you are trying to do here. There is no way to gain access to the local filesystem from browser javascript

Comment: IMO not duplicate, 
@user1058860 see the [solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26181292/2368696), what is your goal using FILE API?

Comment: But, for what it's worth, it appears the first arg to the `File` constructor should be an array, probably of binary data. You really probably shouldn't ever need to use the `File` object directly

Comment: I am just trying to pass the first two words of the text file into variables to print to the web page