# Electron:Javascript VM86 vid.js:56Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: electron, atom-editor

```
var filepath="path of a file";
var txtFile = new File(filepath);
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Arahnoid/9925725 link from github

Answer (score 2):

The error says "2 arguments required". So you need two arguments.

Try

```
var txtFile = new File([""], filepath);
```

see [How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)