# How to get File object from Javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I have used this code for getting File object of a input file (I have tested it by console.log and it is correct).

```
var file = event.target.files[0];
```

The object code that I obtain it's like:

```
File
 lastModified: 1526981976000
​ lastModifiedDate: Date 2018-05-22T09:39:36.000Z
 Name:"path.png"
 size: 19776
 type: "image/png"
 webkitRelativePath: ""...
```

However, now I want to get that kind of File object, but through a image path saved into my file system.  Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)

Comment: Not possible in-browser; the browser has no access to the file system.

Comment: Check  [File Object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181292/4308418)

Answer (score 3):

```
    function handleFiles() {
    "use strict";
    var inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
    var fileList = inputElement.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
    var file = {type:"", name:"", size:""};

    for(var k = 0; k < fileList.length; k++){   
    file.name.push(fileList[k].name);
    file.type.push(fileList[k].type);
    file.size.push(fileList[k].size);
    //and others
    }
```

This works for multiple images files try it

```
    <h2>Upload images ...</h2>
    <input type="file" id="input" multiple onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

Comment: Yes I know, but now that image is saved in my file system and I want to get it from Javascript into File object

Comment: Im sry but i believe that cant be done, the browser cant access the client file system, that would be a huge red flag

Answer (score 2):

The browser can't access the file system of the client, you need to upload the image first

Comment: how dangerous would that be