# Post attachment in Service Now

Tags: rest, servicenow

I'm in a quandary on how to get this working.
In Postman, I can upload an attachment without any issue.
I'm uploading a simple text file.
The code from postmanshows this:

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("uploadFile", "C:\\temp\\test.txt");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://xxxxxxx.service-now.com/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=problem&table_sys_id=oiui5346jh356kj3h634j6hk&file_name=Toast",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "39043b7f-8b2c-1dbc-6a52-10abd25e91c1"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

When I use this on an .asp page I get a 400 error and a response from the console that says:
"Failed to create the attachment. File part might be missing in the request."
How do you get the file you want attach into the code correctly. I thought hard coding it in would have worked. How do you get the code to find the file on the local users pc. Once I get this working I eventually want to have a file input button to select the file.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine except this line:

`form.append("uploadFile", "C:\\temp\\test.txt");`

Passing the file name as the second parameter won't work, according to the documentation of `FormData.append` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append), you need to pass some blob/file object pointing to the document it self (not a string)

Now there are 2 possible scenarios:

**Scenario 1**

The user selects the file manually using a browse button

Here you need to add the input to your page and a trigger to upload the file when it's selected, something like below maybe:

```js
uploadDataFile();

function uploadDataFile(fileInput) {
  // creates the FormData object
  var form = new FormData();
  // get the first file in the file list of the input 
  // (you will need a loop instead if the user will select many files)
  form.append("uploadFile", fileInput.files[0]);
  // ... the rest of your AJAX code here ...
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="uploadDataFile(this)" />
```

**Scenario 2**

Uploading the file directly without user intervention

Here you need to construct the file object manually same as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181292/4374511) and then you will add it normally to your data object

```js
function uploadDataFile() {
  // creates the file object
  var fileObject = new File (...);
  // creates a data object and appends the file object to it
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("uploadFile", fileObject);
  // ... the rest of your AJAX code here ...
}
```

**One final note**

Please pay attention to the browser compatibility for `FormData` & `File` objects