# upload file contents stored in a string as file, to server without writing any file locally

Tags: node.js, axios

I am trying to upload a string which stores contents of a pdf in base64 to server. In my earlier approach I was using following code

```
  var form = new FormData();
  form.append("file", fs.createReadStream(filePath));
  let response=await axios.post(url, form,  {headers: {
    ...form.getHeaders(),
  }});
```

But in this approach I had to write string contents to temporary file first. I want to avoid it. So I need some help. The data in string is obtained from PDFMake tool.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to instantiate a File object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @Max This question is related to nodejs