# Can I retrieve an image into Firebase Storage service as File object?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-storage, primeng

I am working on an Angular application using PrimeNG and storing some uploaded image on Firebase Storage service.

In order to upload images I am using this PrimeNG component named **FileUpload**: https://primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/fileupload

Then the images are correctly saved on Firebase Storage service. It works fine. Each time that I drag and drop an image to be uploaded I have something like this:

[image]

As you can see in the previous screenshot, eacht time that I drag and drop an image I obtain this **uploadedFiles** array that contains object having **File** as type.

What exactly is this **File** type? Is it a PrimeNG custom type or is it this JS object? (this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File)

In case how can I retrieve a specific image from Firebase Storage service into one of this File object?

Comment: 1. Yes, `File` is a native javascript object in browsers. 
2. Can you construct a File object? Yes, see here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8390855/how-to-instantiate-a-file-object-in-javascript), but in most cases you would never need to do this

---
Why do you want to do this? if you tell us what you need to do, we can likely suggest you a much better way to do it. the `File` object is mainly an api available for developers to interact with uploaded/generated files. 
---

Comment: Because I want to recreate an array of File object in order to use it with the PrimeNG FileUpload component into an edit mode view. So into the File Upload PrimeNG component I want to show the file realted to a specific item

Comment: and why on earth would you need the actual file contents to create `File` objects to show the previously uploaded files? you can just retrieve info about the uploaded images and create fake file objects for use with that component, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I retrieve a specific image from Firebase Storage service into one of this File object?

After a file is uploaded to Firebase Storage, there is no way in the Firebase JavaScript SDK to get it directly to a local file. While the iOS and Android SDKs have this option, the JavaScript SDK only allows [downloading the data via a so-called download URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url).

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly shown in the console that File is a javascript array which may contain multiple uploaded image object. To get the first image object you do something like that -

```
File[0].objectURL.SafeUrlImpl
```

The previous line of code will retrieve the object URL.