# How to read local files using HTML 5 FileReader?

Tags: javascript, html, readfile

### Objective

I am making an application, and I need to read a local file using JavaScript and HTML 5, without any `<input>` tags or user interaction whatsoever.

### What I tried

On my research, I found two tutorials that are heavily cited in SO:

- https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api

However, there is a problem. Both of this tutorials require user interaction via the `input` tag, which is a life killer since I want to read the contents of the file automatically into a string.

### Code

So far I managed to get the following code:

```
let readFile = function(path) {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var text = reader.result;
        console.log(text);
    };

    // Read in the image file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsText(MissingFileHandle);
};
```

But as you can see, I am missing an important step, I am missing `MissingFileHandle`. My idea would be to pass a `path` to this method, and so the method would read the file locally as text and print it into the console, but I am unable to achieve this.

### Question

Given a relative path, how can I read the contents of a file using HTML 5 without using `<input>` tags?

Comment: its a security risk that browsers are miminizing when they force user interaction to select a file.

Comment: So, you're saying that what I want is in fact impossible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTML5 fileReader facility does allow you to process local files, but these MUST be selected by the user, you cannot go rooting about the users disk looking for files.

[Is it possible to load a file with JS/HTML5 FileReader on non served page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473837/is-it-possible-to-load-a-file-with-js-html5-filereader-on-non-served-page)

[How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

[How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

[Javascript read file without using input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115057/javascript-read-file-without-using-input)

These links help you to find answer.

Comment: You're right. Even `filereader.readAsText(new File([], 'dir/file.txt'))` does not work.

Answer (score -4):

This Can do a trick.

HTML

```
        <h1>Text File Reader</h1>
        <div>
            Select a text file: 
            <input type="file" id="fileInput">
        </div>
        <pre id="fileDisplayArea"><pre>

    </div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function() {
        var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
        var fileDisplayArea = document.getElementById('fileDisplayArea');

        fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            var file = fileInput.files[0];
            var textType = /text.*/;

            if (file.type.match(textType)) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    fileDisplayArea.innerText = reader.result;
                }

                reader.readAsText(file);    
            } else {
                fileDisplayArea.innerText = "File not supported!"
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: ok you want without UI?

Comment: var file = "Give your file path here"

Comment: It is not what OP wants... So it does not work (in the way he/she wants it to)