# How to show the compiled css from a .less file in the browser?

Tags: less

What is the best way to show the resulting css from files compiled with **less.js** in the client.
In other words, how can i fill a div with the resulting css?

I need to display the result on the page, any way to do this?

THanks!

Comment: Hey can you help me?? I want to hide compiled css from .less file in browser. I didn't want to show it to end user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**update**

As already pointed out in the comments by @ertrzyiks you should replace less.parse with [less.render](http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage) for Less v 2.x:

```
var lessCode = '';
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
    var options = {}
    lessCode = xmlhttp.responseText;
    less.render(lessCode, options, function (error, output) {
    if(!error) {
    document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = output.css;
    }
    else document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = '<span style="color:red">' + error + '</span>';
    });

  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET","important.less",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

see also: [How to detect and print changing variables LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437697/how-to-detect-and-print-changing-variables-less/29452489)

But since Less v2:

> In the browser, less.pageLoadFinished will be a promise, resolved when
>   less has finished its initial processing. less.refresh and
>   less.modifyVars also return promises.

When you compile `filename.less` the compiled CSS code has been inject in a `style` tag with `id` `less:filename`, so to get the compilled CSS code you can also use:

```
less.pageLoadFinished.then(
    function() {
        console.log(document.getElementById('less:filename').innerHTML);
    }
);
```

Notice that the last example also applies the compiled CSS code on the page.

--end update

I expected that running something such as the following was possible:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="important.less">
    <script src="less-1.7.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    css = less.tree.toCSS();
    console.log(css);
    </script>
```

unfortunately this does not work, but you can use the following code to get what you want:

```
    <script src="less-1.7.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    var lessCode = '';
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.status == 200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        lessCode = xmlhttp.responseText;
        new(less.Parser)().parse(lessCode, function (e, tree) {
        document.getElementById('lesscode').innerHTML = tree.toCSS().replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
        });

      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","important.less",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    </script>
```

With in the `body` section of your HTML:

```
<div id="lesscode"></div>
```

See also: [Combining two .less files in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205110/combining-two-less-files-in-one/24415747) and [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Comment: Why is there still the LINK element?

Comment: It is there by accident, it is not needed any more.

Comment: In Less v2 you have less.render() method to do this, see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SBw0KjtPiGSScPZakR1x?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I just use **Chrome's Inspect Element**.

Right click on the element CSS you are looking for, Right click and choose **Inspect element**. On the right you will find the compiled CSS in Styles. Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear, I need to display the result on the page, any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to do this, Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Let's start with Firefox. If you install the [web developer toolbar](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/), you get a menu option that's labelled CSS. Clicking on this gives you a few options and if you choose View CSS, you are taken to a new tab that shows you all of the styles for the page, grouped by their location and you should see a section with the CSS that has been generated by LESS and dynamically applied to the elements.

IE also has a Web Developer option and if you use the toolbar to inspect an element, you can then use the short cut 'Ctrl + T' which will bring up the page source with the computed styles.

The Firefox solution is better, as you can see exactly which styles have been provided by LESS whereas IE just lumps it all together.

There is a third option, and that is to compile the CSS server side!