# How do I get compiled LESS code?

Tags: css, less

I am using less.js for development and was wondering how I get the compiled css code for a live site.

I have looked at the source code and obviously it references only this file `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/test.less">`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show the compiled css from a .less file in the browser? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798122/how-to-show-the-compiled-css-from-a-less-file-in-the-browser)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options to get the generated css

### Fragment of css file

You can view the css in the browser, you will won't be able to get the full generated file, but you can see how each individual element is styled

- Chrome & Safari

  - Right click anywhere on page and click `Inspect Element`
- IE9+

  - Press F12
- Firefox

  - Right click anywhere on page and click `Inspect Element`

### Generate full css file

- **Windows**

  - [Winless](http://winless.org/)
- **OSX**

  - [Simpless](http://wearekiss.com/simpless)
  - [Less.app](http://incident57.com/less/)

### Ports

- [dotless](https://github.com/dotless/dotless) (windows - .NET/linux - mono)
- [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/)

---

## Update

[@crashdesk suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938608/how-do-i-get-compiled-less-code/10938820#comment14309986_10938820) the [Web Developer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm?hl=en-US&utm_source=chrome-ntp-launcher) extension for Chrome.
You can view the whole file in the browser. After installing, click on the icon, then 'CSS', then 'View CSS'.

Comment: Do they have the code completion feature ? That's a big issue for me when searching for a text editor. I've been using Pycharm and recently found that it has code complete with less files as well.

Comment: I will use Simpless I think. No way I am going through all elements to get the css :-)

Comment: @Crashdesk That would be a nightmare, just thought I would throw out all available options.

Comment: @guanome found out that I can just use the web developer extension on google chrome...just click 'View CSS' and job done. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

A manual way of doing it is just viewing the generated source from your HTML file and copying the compiled CSS source.

Comment: I think that is what the question is, how do you view the generated css?