# Open file with link button

Tags: c#, html, webforms, asplinkbutton

***edited***
Does anyone know how to upload/open a file in a shared location on a intranet with a link button either from the markup or programmatically?

```
 <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnGetFile" CommandName="GetFile" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("FormName") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Just to understand the request - you want to open a file on a user's computer by clicking a link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Comment: it will be on a intranet. Is there something better than a link button to use?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better stated as uploading and opening the file

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about files on your local computer, is that correct? If so according to [this site](http://forums.asp.net/t/1076148.aspx/2/10), it cannot be done in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working from a web application there are a lot of security restrictions when it comes to accessing local files. If you are writing the application for use locally you might be able to give permissions to open local files by giving the DefaultAppPool User access to the files in question.

Îf you are planning on puttting your app on the web on the other hand, you options are pretty limited.

Hope this helps!