# function to empty a files content

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a function that empties a files content if a button is clicked when the value is not etmpy, is this at all possible?

```
function file_empty() {

    var file = document.getElementById('file');

     if(file.value !=="") {
        // empty the file
          return true;
    }
}

<input  name="uploaded" type="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" value="empty-if-full" onclick="return file_empty();" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible. JavaScript has **zero** access to the file system.

A server-side language (C#, VB, PHP, ColdFusion, Ruby, etc.) is required to do what you want.

Comment: good to know, guess I'll have to figure something else out, thanks

Answer (score 1):

file system is something which cannot be reached by frontend-scripts. js is one of them. i was also struggling to open and write into file by js, it is also hardly possible.. so you should stick to something like php, python, java etc...

Comment: "unfortunately, file system is something which cannot be reached by frontend-scripts" = overall, it's not unfortunate.

Comment: i meant to the pity of his case. not overall!

Answer (score 1):

As the @james sir says its not possible with javascript but you can lookat html5 filereader.

Here you can check [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-local-disk-file-with-javascript)