# How to read local machine file without using DOM/ drag and drop event and mouse event using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck to read my local machine file using java script without using any event handling and DOM file element.
my scenarios is"

I have a xml file having a column say( fileLocation) which will have the value like "D:\test\test.doc". I am uploading this file using php script on the server.

Now I read that column value (file location of the local machine) and trying to read data from that location
but stuck becoze my application is working on server and file is located at my local computer.

So please suggest how can i read data of the file from that location.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open local disk file with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Comment: So, **No**, this is not possible, and the question's been asked before. Please search before asking a question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the file using an `<input type="file" />` field inside `<form enctype=" multipart/form-data" method="post" />`. You can then access the file in PHP using the `$_FILES` array.

As far as I know, it is not possible to access a file using JavaScript on the client side since this would open up a whole new world of security issues.

Comment: thanks for reply, I think so, but may be there is a way to solve it.