# SWT Browser location listener event returns about:blank

Tags: java, html, browser, swt, dom-events

I'm using SWT Browser which is being filled by setting the browser's text (due to dynamic html changes).
I want to add a location listener in order to get values from the html and use it in the Java code,
but I get `about:blank#` instead of the link I'm sending in the html file.

Java code:

```
    if (browser == null) {
        browser = new Browser(browserComposite, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    }

    browser.setText(os.toString(),true);
    browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    browser.addLocationListener(new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void changing(LocationEvent e) {
            System.out.println(e.location);
            e.doit = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void changed(LocationEvent e) {
            e.doit = false;
        }

    });
```

html code:

```
<script>
   function myFunc(vars) {
      window.location="http://www.google.com";
   }
   function recordVariableUse(nodes, vars) {
      for (var i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
          nodes[i].onclick=function() {myFunc(vars)}
      }
   }
   recordVariableUse(document.getElementsByClassName("x"), ["y"]);
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Comment: Does it work if you use a proper web url instead of a local file?

Comment: Baz - yes. I've tried "http://www.google.com"
It doesn't work only in the swt browser, I managed to run it in chrome\iexplorer

Comment: @DanaKlein Try assigning the url to `window.location.href` instead. There have been issues when omitting the `href` in the past. Not sure if this actually makes a difference in this case here.

Comment: no luck either. :\ the LocationEvent still returns about:blank#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a local disk file with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)