# How to send and store data in an XML file, using an HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I need to create a report generation system which sends the reports to a DB. Can I replace the DB with an XML file, so that I don't have to use a server. Is it even possible?

Comment: If you want multiple users to share the same XML file you'll have to have a server to store that copy. If all you need is one file you might be able to get away with hosting this file on some service like github or dropbox.

Comment: no, only one user will be accessing the application.

Comment: Ok - how does this user access the system? Does it only exist locally on one machine?

Comment: yeah it exists locally. And actions performed by the user would go into that XML file, can it be done?

Comment: If all you have is a single browser running local JavaScript I don't think that there is currently an option to write data to files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an HTML 5 web page that generates an xml file and let the user save it. 
On the next time the user can supply the page with the last generated xml. 
Look here: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Also, you can use HTML 5 key value store for loading every time the last data file generated.

I would recommend exploring those 2 options, and maybe later on adding a server to store the data.