# Read Text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could you please tell me whether there is any way of reading and displaying the value from the text file using Javascript when I open the HTML page?

The file is in the local system and it needs to be picked up automatically when the HTML page opens up and the result should be displayed in alert message as well as in the HTML page.

Comment: Not possible. The user has to at least select the file in an `<input type="file" />` element.

Comment: @Sirko can't we specify the file name and its location instead in the JS?

Comment: If you could do it completely automatic, you could read any content from a user's harddrive: passwords, private files, ... If you need "permanent" storage on a client's computer look at cookies and `localStorage`.

Comment: @Sirko How to look into localStorage?

Comment: [`localStorage`@MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage).

Answer (score 2):

See [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript), it is NOT possible to load local files using plain javascript.

However, we can use [HTML5 file APIs](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) to facilitate the loading of user specified files.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for this

```
   var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
  var ForReading = 1;
  var f1 = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\file.txt", ForReading);
  var text = f1.ReadAll();
  f1.close();
  alert( text);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Be careful, because this will only work in Internet Explorer.