# JS: Submit HTML file and place file code within div

Tags: javascript, html, upload

Basically what im looking for is a way for the user to upload an html file when they click
`<input type="file"/>` button.

When the user selects an HTML file, I want to take the HTML code and place it within a div. Can this be done without server-side languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript You cannot browse on a clients disk files. However your case is possible. Please check the below stackover question which exactly matches your requirement. Refer Paolo Moretti answer. 
Here is the link: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

As you want to browse/upload only HTML files add "accept" to your input file type like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="text/html"/>
```

In HTML5 you can use file extensions as the accept like this:

```
<input type="file" accept=".html"/>
```