# PHP temporarily work with a file

Tags: php, csv, post, get, put

I want to be able to upload a CSV file to a Webpage, and then have PHP store that information to a array and do stuff with it WITHOUT saving the CSV file to the server. How is that possible?

Looking into it, there's the normal `GET` and `POST`, which upload the file to the server. There's also `PUT`, but it looks like it just saves on top of an already existing file on the server.
And from the looks of the process to extract data from a CSV, PHP needs to know the location of the file.

Is it possible to just have the PHP work with the CSV file without saving it to the server somewhere? That way I don't have to worry about security issues with uploading files to a server. I don't need to hold onto the CSV data afterwords, just manipulate it in the current session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a file is uploaded to the server from a form, the file is stored temporarily ( `$_FILES['someinputname']['tmp_name']` ) . No one says you have to do anything with this file before you can use it. You can read directly from the temporary path and forget about it. This, of course, does not leave you free from harm. Validating the file type is what you expect and not of malicious nature MUST be done before doing anything with a file you don't trust.

No lazy way around being safe.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is just a text file. So you can read the file using javascript from client side and get the text from the file.

[Javascript - read local text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

And then send the text to server and then work with it.