# HTML file in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, file

I would like to use jQuery to replace the contents of an HTML tag with a file.

I have the following code: `$("html").html(hi.html)`.

While it works if I instead put a quote, it doesn't work if I put a file. How do I achieve this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Perhaps you're looking for `.load()`?

Comment: @EdCottrell is right, I think load() is what you want. .html() will replace the innerHTML of an element with HTML passed as a string containing HTML tags. While .load() will download a file and load its content into the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit ambiguous. I am assuming you are trying to load a local file rather than a file served from a server. If you are looking for later, then gregg's answer will suffice.

You can use html5's File reader api to read contents of a file stored locally on your machine. Sample implementation: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

Helpful links:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Hope this helps if this is what you are looking for.