# Html tags doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a new html file by clicking a submit button but it doesn't work
my code is here

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
                        <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="submitFunction()">Confirm SignUp</button>
                    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function submitFuntion(){
            if(document.getElementById('submit').onclick){
                document.write("<a href='info.html'></a>");
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place submit button inside a `form` tag and set its attribute `action` to info.html. that way when you click on submit info.html will open. No need of click event for submit button

Answer (score 1):

Solution with form/submit:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-3">
  <form action="info.html">
    <button 
      id="submit" 
      type="submit" 
      class="btn btn-default">
        Confirm SignUp
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='info.html'">Confirm SignUp </button>
```

This will help you navigate to the page `info.html` on clicking the submit button.