# Read input stream of file before uploading to server - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I want to read the input stream of a file before it starts uploading to the server.
This is the way I get the input stream.

```
 FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
```

But this method executes after the file has uploaded.I see in the buttom left corner an upload progress. Is it possible to read the bytes of the file before the upload starts ?

Comment: show more of your code so we can see how you are currently handling things

Answer (score 0):

there is an example how you could read file in browser and examine its content using javascript qoute from:
[open file using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

```
 function readSingleFile(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  if (!file) {
    return;
  }
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    displayContents(contents);
  };
  reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
  var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
  element.innerHTML = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
  .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

And in html you could have

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
<pre id="file-content"></pre>
```

Comment: this is better suited to be a comment not an answer..!

Comment: @MethodMan - thx for direction ... need to wait until 50 :-)