# JavaScript - Open a file from localdisk

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am new to `Javascript`. I want to `open a file` from the localsystem only not from server ,when the user clicks on a single item from a list .So, I dont know how to open a file in `javascript`.so,can any one help me to figure it out ?

Comment: You can found an answere [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

Comment: I have tried that already. But its not working...

Comment: Did you check [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from @PaoloMoretti.

See this link:

[How to Open Local Disk File With Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Hope this helps,

Tim

**CODE:**

```
   function readSingleFile(e) {
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      if (!file) {
        return;
      }
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        displayContents(contents);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }



    function displayContents(contents) {
      var element = document.getElementById('file-content');
      element.innerHTML = contents;
    }

    document.getElementById('file-input')
      .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    <h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
    <pre id="file-content"></pre>
```

Comment: Please do not copy answers from other questions. This question should be marked as a duplicate instead.

Comment: Ok, no problem. How do I do that?

Comment: Once you have more reputation, you can vote to mark questions as duplicate. For now, just leave a comment like Jean-Charbel VANNIER did.