# how to click a file in desktop using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using selenium ide. It is working fine for my minimal functionalities.At middle of application need to perform some windows action.for that i have made a script using some third party tool. And i converted that to some .bat file .now I want to click that file by creating one html page in that i have created a button.

Now real problem facing how to place my .bat file in that button(if i click that button my bat file has to run).

Comment: Javascript can not interact with a user's desktop (and that's a good thing, because it would be a huge security issue).

Comment: Duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript