# Save and load files with three.js

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there a way to save and load stringified objects with three.js?

I found this: https://github.com/josdirksen/learning-threejs/blob/master/chapter-08/03-load-save-json-object.html

but they use `localstorage` to save and load, which won't work between sessions or different computers.

Is there a way to load files just like the model is loaded? This should be like loading data files for a game.

I run the webgl client with Autodesk viewer locally with `http-server`.

Comment: You can save/read from files using the File API but the user will be prompted always where to save for each save. To save outside of various local storage you need a server. [See this article](https://games.greggman.com/game/saving-and-loading-files-in-a-web-page/) for how to get started writing such a server

Comment: But there's already a server that serves the model files, why I can't use that? @gman

Comment: Maybe you can but you'll need to add functions and routes for loading and saving. Saving files is not generally a standard server feature, it's a feature you add on to meet your project's needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Object can be written to localstorage it can just as well be exported as a file. You can send them to a server and store them there (maybe something like firebase would be useful here), or you can intiate a "download" directly from the browser. This is explained in [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server).

For loading a file, you can use the file-api, which is shown here: [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

You just need to replace the localstorage-parts in your example accordingly.

Comment: Why I can't use the same server that serves the model files?

Comment: Sure, you can do that as well. But you stated you are using http-server, which afaik doesn't support PUT or POST-requests to store files on the server. That's why I gave some options for doing this with a pure static server.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43311706/4838205), the Autodesk Viewer uses files translated and hosted by [Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2). It's possible to show multiple files into the same scene. The Viewer is read-only. There is a getState and loadState functions to get the objects that represents the current zoom/explode/view information, and that can be serialized and stored somewhere.

There are [some samples](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.ModelTransformer) showing how to move a geometry on the model, for instance, move the geometry of a wall (from a building model). But that is not persistent, meaning you need to implement a JavaScript (client) + back-end infrastructure to save and restore those transformations.