# js data transform from csv to a specific format, error to load csv

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have a csv file :

```
title,number1,number2
M,12,22
T,17,27
W,7,17
T,17,27
F,23,33
```

And I want something written in this format in my js file because the rest of the program use datas with this format. It will be hard to modify all the code. I prefer to work on csv transform.

```
dataDailySalesChart = {
        labels: ['M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F'],
        series: [
            [12, 17, 7, 17, 23],
            [22, 27, 17, 27, 33]
        ]
    };
```

I tried this code but it didn't work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.csv",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });
    });

    function processData(allText) {

        var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
        var serie1 = allTextLines[1].split(',');
        var serie2 = allTextLines[2].split(',');
        var seriesTest = [serie1,serie2];

        dataDailySalesChart = {
            labels: headers,
            series: seriesTest
        };

    }
```

But I have the error :

```
jquery-3.1.0.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file: test.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https
```

Do you know why I get this error ?

Comment: Use Papa Parse http://papaparse.com/

Comment: @ArvindDhakad Why would you do that? The question is tagged [d3.js] which comes with its own means for parsing DSV content.

Comment: Because I have want to re use a code using d3js but not for the datas. The datas are written directly in the js file like "dataDailySalesChart". And I want the same report but using data in my csv. To be more flexible. Anybody can change a csv, but not the js. I though it was easier to change just this part, instead all the d3js code written which use the dataDailySalesChart

Comment: @altocumulus obviously DSV is there he can use it. Papa Parse is an alternative.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what DSV is. I am really noob I said

Comment: It means *Delimiter-separated values*. Back to your question, what do you want? If you cannot change the JS, there is no point asking any question here.

Comment: Please break this down into smaller parts...first figure out how to use d3 to parse your csv...then work on transforming it. Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service or a free code writing service. The objective here is to help you fix **your code**

Comment: I can change the js. But if I change the format of dataDailySalesChart, I need to change all the d3js which used this. So I though it was better to prepare my csv to fil the format of dataDailySalesChart. Am I wrong in my reasoning ?

Comment: Ok, now it's more clear. By the way, what's your country? You have semicolons in that CSV, which is not valid for `d3.csv`. I suspect you live in a country that uses comma as decimal separator.

Comment: Yes, I am french

Comment: I modified my post if you want to check it again.

Comment: You have a cross-origin error when loading your file. Where do you try to load the csv file from?

Comment: this is a html file which read the js file. I tried to open it on Chrome, Mozilla. Same problem

Comment: You cannot load files from file system when you execute a webpage locally.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    // This is causing the error: test.csv is not a valid url
    url: "test.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data);}
});
```

Where do you try to load your csv file from? test.csv is not a valid url for an ajax request. You shoud either request it from the same domain the page is loaded on with `/path/to/test.csv` or from a different domain with sth. like `https://somedomain.com/path/to/test.csv`

Comment: It didn't work with url: "/Projet/dashboard1/donnees/test.csv". it should work ?

Comment: I already commented under the question: you are executing your HTML locally. That means there is no webserver running. You cannot use ajax to read from the local file system. Your webpage needs to run on a webserver to work that way.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find another way... Thank you

Comment: The only way to read a local file from disk to use it in your script is to make the user select it manually via `<input type="file">`.