# Can I write a script on my website that open and read or edit files on my computer like fopen() or something with another web language?

Tags: web

I'm wondering if there is a way to **open** and edit or read the data inside a file on **my computer** from **my website** ? Is there is a programming language that can achieve that ?

I'm talking about a real website, not a local .php file for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that using PHP, but you can do it with javascript. Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).