# Angular 5 open a excel file

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

In Angular 5 (Typescript) web app.
How to open an existing Excel file from a hard drive, please?

In my previous Java projects, we used servlets for this. But this is a NodeJS project.

**Update:-**

I tried other options like below but got chrome error - "**Not allowed to load local resource:**"

```
<a href="file://c:/test.xls" target="_blank">Click me!</a>
```

Are there any serverside options available using NodeJS, Express, etc?
Still trying to figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Comment: A web app cannot access a users hard drive directly to get files out, as that would be a huge security issue. Imagine if you went onto facebook and it could steal all your pictures out of your pictures folder.

If you meant something else then please clarify :)

You can ask the user to select the file using a file input though.

Comment: @Mongoose Thanks, yes these files are stored in network hard drive. Are there any other alternatives to open files stored in network?

Comment: Is the network drive accessible publicly, or on the same network as your web server? If so, you could potentially code a back-end solution to retrieve the files from the network drive,.

Comment: This is an internal web application and the file is stored in the internal network.

Comment: Why not create a WebService that can access the internal files, exposes a HTTP interface, and then from your WebApp perform a Get for that file?

Comment: @BeniMurza Thanks, I would try that.