# Get full path of selected file in PHP

Tags: php, input, file-io

I want to select file with an input tag, but this don't return me full path of selected file(full directory).

I try this code in edge browser and return me full path of selected file but other browser can't.

this my form :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filedir = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
```

any idea??
plz help

Comment: untill you save file to somewhere in folder the file stays in temp folder location. so i didn't get why you need temp folder path.

Comment: When you upload a file to the server. The server has access to the original file name, and the temporary name and location (stored on the server). **The server does not get the full directory from the client's machine**, which is what I think you are alluding to.

Comment: i dont need temp directory...i need directory of selected file....for example c:\text1.txt

Comment: @Emad Is that not what `tmp_name` is? Use the temporary name/location to `move_uploaded_file`

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i understand from **your** Question.

#### You need full path for the file to **open** it or work on it:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
   $FileData file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
   echo $FileData;
   //Data inside the file will be shown in the browser
}
```

#### You need "**real**" path use:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
   echo realpath($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
}
```

#### If you mean path from **client** **side**:

This is PHP. PHP is **server side**. it means the data and everything will is working by the server/computer and the **browser** has no power to edit it. It receives only data and the server will work with it(with what **you** coded)

#### If you want to open the file **without** sending it to the **server**:

[This answer will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298948/6523558)
Hope i get what you want