# how to access file name in typescript from directory

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular 4 and not getting any solution to read file name from folder directory. Can someone please share some code how to access file name in typescript?

Comment: remember, this is a web app - you can't read files from the file system.

Comment: means there is no option to read file name as we do in c#. [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

Comment: You can read the content of a given file on the file system, however, walking a directory and finding file names programmatically will not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)