# Read data from text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, file

I'm trying to make a complex website, and I want to split it into multiple files, one of them is the content itself, and for that I want to make a function that changes a div content from the file.

The entire code :

```
<html>
    <body onLoad = "uploadData();">
        <div id = "text"> </div>
    </body>
    <script>
    function uploadData()
    {
        var file = new File("data");
        file.open("r");
        var data = "";
        while (!file.eof) {
            data += file.readln() + "\n";
        }
        file.close();
        alert(data);
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = data;
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

The code has an error at line 7.
Please help me !!!

Comment: Read up on how to use ajax

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a complex website, you need a web server. Let's assume your content does not need server side rendering and you have Apache installed, then a plain XHR function can help you fetching the content. If plain XHR is not helpful, jQuery perhaps can ease things.

Comment: I do not want to make this website public. I want to make it just for me !

Answer (score 3):

You cannot read from a file this way in a ***modern*** browser for [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security) (the scripts are [sandboxed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(computer_security))).

Maybe you took those functions from a very old and non-standard Javascript reference like *JavaScript Programmer's Reference* (by Cliff Wootton, 2001) or *Pure JavaScript*
(by Charlton Ting, Jason Gilliam, Allen R. Wyke, 1999). Those are very antique manuals and deal with obsolete browser versions (Internet Explorer 4...).

You can also find those functions or a similar set in the APIs provided by JS engines like Adobe InDesign, NodeJS or ShellJS, **which are not browser engines**. Working with a JS engine doens't imply you'll find the same API as provided by another one. Typically, you won't do the same things with NodeJS and Firefox JS engine (OdinMonkey currently).

If you want to dynamically change the content of your page (ie its DOM structure) with an external resource (a file located in your server), use the **[Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)** techniques.

Finally, [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript), you'll find some ways to get the content of a local file, but they **must have been selected manually** by the user.