# Displaying a generated JSON file on a simple website

Tags: javascript, java, html, json, file

I have a Java tool, which schedules a task every 24 hours and writes the result in a result.json file. Now I want to display this result.json file on a simple website, but I know that it's not natively possible with JavaScript to access local files. But what other, simple ways exist for this problem? I try to avoid a webservice to keep the scheduling-program and the website on the same server.

Thanks!

Comment: When loading the page, grab the result.json file via an JavaScript XHR request and display the response text on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the object `FileReader` for read the file stream from your system and gets the JSON file in a string, later use `JSON.parse()` to get the JSON in JS object and iterate over it for pretty representing in document DOM, or you can print the string in the HTML without parse to JS object.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298948/8494761) there are a very completely example of FileReader.

Comment: In all examples I find about the FileReader there is a input where you first have to upload a file. How can i directly program the path to a file? Can i specify a filepath myself?

Comment: JS can't access to file system correctly, but you can upload the file with a file type input in a form.... another way would be access with AJAX but yes... you need a microservice.

Comment: I decided to simply write a basic webservice in Java EE. I think this will spare me some stress. I don't want to find any tricky solution, which only works partially. But thanks for the help!