# How can i open a file browser using a specific path/drive letter in Html/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, linux

Use case :
Open file browser of the specific stored location.
Requirement:
I have an Interface to mention the drive letter/mount point and the path of it. This is stored at the server level. Now, from UI when i click on a button(for this task), file browser should open at that specific stored location only. How do i handle this case from UI?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript, maybe this helps you out?