# HTML- How can I insert the contents of a .txt file into a variable to use .innerHTML to change the contents of <body>?

Tags: javascript, html, external, txt

Im trying to create an automated system for HTML page handling where I will be able to change the contents
of a`<div>` inside `<body>` by writing into an external `.txt` file and uploading it to the server. Im still an early student in university
and I havent learned PHP and JQuery yet. So I am trying to accomplish this by using only Javascript and HTML.
I just need a way for whatever I write inside the .txt file to be written again inside the `<div class="CONTENT"  id="target">` which is inside the `<body>` automatically. Any thoughts and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're probably going to want to handle this in the server. Perhaps instead of rewriting the HTML file, you have your server grab all your .txt files, wrap them in <div> tags, then wrap the whole thing in HTML tags, and finally send that HTML as the response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by using the FileReader.
Have a look to
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript).

```js
function readSingleFile(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    if (!file) {
        return;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var contents = e.target.result;
        displayContents(contents);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function displayContents(contents) {
    var element = document.getElementById('target');
    element.textContent = contents;
}

document.getElementById('file-input')
    .addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="file-input" />
    <h3>Contents of the file:</h3>
    <div id="target" class="CONTENT"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A link only answer should not be an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: All you've done is copied the code from the link. Still a link only answer. You haven't added anything that isn't in the link.

Comment: Thank you @ScottMarcus for your clarification. I can't comment with less than 50 reputations. Should I remove the response?

Comment: Yes, you really should. For now, focus on providing quality answers to get your reputation up. You may want to read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can make an [AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for the text file and take the response from that call and set that as the `.textContent` of the `div`. Here's an example (see comments inline):

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");

// Create XHR object
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Configure the request (substitute a URL
// to the file below)
xhr.open("GET", filePathHere, false);

// Set up the callback for when the response has
// been recieved
xhr.onreadystatechange = function (){
 if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
   // Was the request successful?
   if(xhr.status === 200 || xhr.status == 0) {
     // Populate the <div> with the response text
     output.textContent = xhr.responseText;
   }
 }
}
xhr.send(null);  // Make the call
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```