# Can I use an existing folder of images for kNN image classification, HTML & JS

Tags: javascript, html, knn

I'm trying to create a project on posture detection using HTML and JAVASCRIPT. I've already taken pictures of a few people with the intention of creating a dataset for k-NN classification. I've separated a folder of images that represents the healthy, and another for unhealthy.

I've searched all over the internet and I've realized that no one talks about how to use an existing folder of images and directly put it in a class. For example, putting the healthy imgs folder in the healthy posture class, and likewise, the unhealthy imgs folder in the unhealthy posture class. Everyone creates an interface that classifies imgs by clicking a button to take an image, saving that img to the k-NN model then, loading it again upon page refresh.

How can I create a k-NN class by simply adding a whole folder of imgs that I've already prepared? Is it even possible?

Comment: Unless you have a server running, you can't read disk files directly without user input/selection. It's a security feature. @CarsonC

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582755/5120049

Comment: Are there any suggestions for how I should be approaching this project from now on? @Vishnudev

Comment: Use a Node.js server.