# How to read and manipulate files with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to make a page on my site which allows input of a number of .JSON files, to further combine them into one JSON file. The combined data of which is manipulated and displayed to the user using graphs. I can't seem to find a way to display this data to the user.

My code is as follows. I have a simple html input which leads into some javascript.

```
<input type="file" name="filefield" id="fileList" multiple="multiple" accept=".JSON">

<script>
const fileList = document.getElementById("fileList").files;
console.log(fileList[0]);
</script>
```

I'm trying to output the contents of the JSON file to the console as a test to see that I can access the data. The console however just reads metadata of the given file, not the content within.

Comment: `<input type="file">` is for uploading to a backend server (the same server the .html file is on). Look at the back end language (e.g. PHP) for how to receive the file and process it and send the data back to the front end .html file for further processing. Also, look at chart.js and d3.js for info about displaying charted data.

Comment: Thanks, so for the manipulation of the user data I should upload the files to the server. Is there a reason to not do everything client-side?

Comment: Well, you can't really... If you think about it, the `.html` file is not on the user's computer, it's on the web server. So you already are uploading to the server. However, HTML cannot receive/process uploaded files - but PHP and NodeJS (and ASP and Flask et al) can. PHP is much easier to get started with for most people (it sure was for me).  A great thing to get you started is the [HeyAGeek File Upload jQuery plugin](https://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php). Good examples for both the client-side upload, and for receiving/processing on the back end.

Comment: Well, maybe there is a way on that linked answer - see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26298948). I've never tried that method so I don't know. Good luck to you !